# Can I use the Nullstellensatz?

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry

I have the next system of equations where $a_{ij}\in\mathbb{K}$ for a field $\mathbb{K}$ and are not all zero at the same time. Under what circumstances about the field can I ensure that the next system has a nontrivial solution? I can more or less figure that under the reals it should have and, then also, under the complex numbers. But I do not know about other fields and also about the properties I have to ask for this field to get a nonzero solution. I am also not sure about the use of the Hilbert Nullstellensatz in this situation because it affirms that V(I) is not empty... but I know it because $0\in V(I)$ obviously.

\begin{equation}\label{E}
\left\{
\begin{aligned}
x_{1} &= a_{11}x_{1}^{2}+\cdots+a_{n1}x_{n}^{2}\\
\vdots\\
x_{n} &= a_{1n}x_{1}^{2}+\cdots+a_{nn}x_{n}^{2}.
\end{aligned}
\right.
\end{equation}

What happen in the case $a_{ii}\neq0$ for all $i\in\{1,\dots, n\}$?

Comment: The equations $x_1=x_1^2-x_2^2, x_2=x_1^2-x_2^2$ have no non-trivial solutions over any field.

Comment: Oh, that was easy. I am a bit ashame. I was thinking about the Nullstellensatz and more powerful stuff and I not even saw this counterexample. Do you know if this can be extnded to the cases when $n>2$ and/or the rows are linearly independent? Also, where can I read more about this kind of systems? I know the Nullstellensatz and similar stuff, but they are not helping so much when you are looking for some particular kind of solution (as in this case with non-zero solutions) because they just tell you that there is a solution. I guess work on this systems is related to work in quadrics. Thanks!

Comment: It is trivial to extend this to any $n$. One case where you do have non-trivial solutions is when $k$ is algebraically closed and the quadrics are general.

Comment: It seems to me that the only counterexamples valid for all the fields at the same time are those of the form $x_{1}=\cdots=x_{n}=p(x_{1}, \cdots, x_{n}),$ where $p$ is a polynomial in $n$ variables (having the form required) verifying that $p(x,\cdots, x)=0$. Am I right? If I am, then we can eleminate these pathological cases easily and come back to the question (eliminating these cases) of what are the conditions over the field to get non-zero solutions of the system. Algebraic closedness work, but it is not necessary as it looks like the reals also verify it (at least in dimension 2).

Comment: Well, no, my previous comment is not true in higher dimension and it looks like the trivial cases which push the systems to have just the trivial solution in any field are a bit more complicated to discern to eliminate them from the cases considered. Anyway, it looks that these cases should be easy to identify in order to avoid and are not very numerous. At least in dimension 2 I can not see too many and I am just able to find those derived from the one pointed out by @Mohan.